# Oracle DB : Like with multiple values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

This is my query

```
SELECT dia
FROM CRES
WHERE pro_id = 2
AND 8103434563 LIKE
  ( SELECT dial_pattern||'%' FROM CDIVN WHERE dial_id = 1
  );
```

Now `select dial_pattern||'%' from CDIVN where dial_id = 1` can give `multiple` results. Hence, my main query is failing and reason is `"sub query returns more than one row"`. This is because i have mentioned `like`.

but my logic requires `like` because i want 8103434563 with pattern match condition from table CDIVN.

How do i modify my query. Please help.

=======

```
 CREATE TABLE CDIVN
   (    DIAL_PATTERN_ID NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    DIAL_PATTERN VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    OTHERS VARCHAR2(64 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "CDIVN_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("DIAL_PATTERN_ID", "DIAL_PATTERN")

   );


Insert into CDIVN (DIAL_PATTERN_ID,DIAL_PATTERN,OTHERS) values (1,'810','abc');
Insert into CDIVN (DIAL_PATTERN_ID,DIAL_PATTERN,OTHERS) values (1,'811','xyz');
Insert into CDIVN (DIAL_PATTERN_ID,DIAL_PATTERN,OTHERS) values (1,'812','aaa');
Insert into CDIVN (DIAL_PATTERN_ID,DIAL_PATTERN,OTHERS) values (5,'999','www');
Insert into CDIVN (DIAL_PATTERN_ID,DIAL_PATTERN,OTHERS) values (9,'333','ewe');


  CREATE TABLE CRES
   (    PROFILE_ID NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    PROFILE_NAME VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    DIALLED_PATTERN VARCHAR2(15 BYTE), 
     CONSTRAINT "CRES_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("PROFILE_ID")

   ) ;


Insert into CRES (PROFILE_ID,PROFILE_NAME,DIALLED_PATTERN) values (1,'A','1');
Insert into CRES (PROFILE_ID,PROFILE_NAME,DIALLED_PATTERN) values (2,'B','5');
Insert into CRES (PROFILE_ID,PROFILE_NAME,DIALLED_PATTERN) values (3,'C','9');
```

I have CRES-profile id and one number with me from other sources and these are 1 and 81034345 respectively.

Now `select DIALLED_PATTERN from CRES where PROFILE_ID=1;`

This will give me DIALLED_PATTERN as 1.

Now `select DIAL_PATTERN from CDIVN where DIALLED_PATTERN_ID = 1 ( DIALLED_PATTERN )`

This will give  DIAL_PATTERN as 810, 811, 812.

Now if 81034345 is matching with any one 810% or 811% or 812%. then i need 810% as my answer.

Comment: What is the relationship between `CRES` and `CDIVN` tables to join?

Comment: dial_id. CRES dial_id is foreign key of CDIVN dial_id. SELECT dial_pattern||'%' FROM CDIVN WHERE dial_id = 1, here 1 is CRES-dial_id

Comment: Ok, then you need to JOIN the tables. See my answer.

Comment: Post the create and insert statements and show your desired output. At least create a [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: @Lalit Kumar B : Updated question. Can you please see now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going in right direction, just that you need to **JOIN** the two tables, and no need of sub-query, you could directly use `LIKE dial_pattern||'%'`.

```
SQL> SELECT a.*, b.*
  2  FROM CRES A
  3  JOIN CDIVN b
  4  ON (b.DIAL_PATTERN_ID = A.profile_id)
  5  WHERE TO_CHAR(8103434563) LIKE dial_pattern||'%';

PROFILE_ID PROFILE_NAME DIALLED_PATTERN DIAL_PATTERN_ID DIAL_PATTER OTHERS
---------- ------------ --------------- --------------- ----------- ------
         1 A            1                             1 810         abc
```

Comment: but in CDIVN table, i have multiple dial patterns ie 810, 812, 813 with dial_is as 1. now if 8103434563 matches with anyone ( 810, 812, 813 ) it should return. here 8103434563  matches with 810

Comment: Are you OK if you get all rows where dial_pattern starts with `8`? Or you want only three patterns `810, 812 and 813`? Is `81%` ok for you? That would give you all dial_patterns that starts with `81`.

Comment: in CDIVN table, i have multiple dial patterns ie 810, 812, 813 with dial_is as 1. Now 8103434563 like ( 810%, 812%, 813% ), then its mathing with 810% then it should return value

Comment: should not be b.dial_pattern LIKE %8103434563% but i need 8103434563 like ( pattern match from CDIVN  for ex  810%, 812%, 813% )

Comment: @VJS Ok, see the updated query. Please mark it as answered, would help others too!.

Comment: this is not correct. I have updated my question so that you can understand better. can you please check and revert

Comment: @VJS Post the create and insert statements and show your desired output. At least create a [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: @ Lalit Kumar B : please see my updated question. Can you please revert

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96122/discussion-between-vjs-and-lalit-kumar-b).

Comment: Thanks  @Lalit Kumar B

Comment: If more than one pattern of `CDIVN` matches then you get duplicate results of `CRES`

Comment: @FrankOckenfuss Then it should be fixed at design level with required constraints. i see OP has defined the constraints, and it completely up to OP to tell whether or not `CONSTRAINT "CDIVN_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("DIAL_PATTERN_ID", "DIAL_PATTERN")` could be violated.

Comment: @LalitKumarB  Yes, this constraint should be adapted, because `Insert into CDIVN (DIAL_PATTERN_ID,DIAL_PATTERN,OTHERS) values (1,'810','abc');
Insert into CDIVN (DIAL_PATTERN_ID,DIAL_PATTERN,OTHERS) values (1,'81','xyz');`will produce duplicate results

Comment: @FrankOckenfuss I think OP is aware of it, if you see the number of updates in my answer just go to edits, this was one of the answer at some stage, but OP wanted the current answer in accepted form.

Answer (score 1):

if i may say so, i also had this crazy obsession for sql to have an **IN LIKE** functionality. and to do this, instead of putting the subquery in your criteria, you may write it as a `JOIN` on table `CRES`.

the way i see this is that the subquery

```
( SELECT dial_pattern||'%' FROM CDIVN WHERE dial_id = 1
  );
```

in the criteria does not directly affect the rows from table `CRES` but is being used as a filter for all the results. meaning, if the subquery does not return (a) value(s), the whole query should not return anything as well.

Comment: dial_id. CRES dial_id is foreign key of CDIVN dial_id. SELECT dial_pattern||'%' FROM CDIVN WHERE dial_id = 1, here 1 is CRES-dial_id . Can you suggest how to write

Answer (score 1):

Collect the like-values and build a regexp-expression, e.g.

```
-- Test Data
with CDIVN as
 (select 1 as dial_id, 'ABC' as val
    from dual
  union all
  select 1 as dial_id, 'ACD' as val
    from dual
  union all
  select 1 as dial_id, 'XXA' as val from dual),

CRES as
 (select 2 as proc_id, 'ABCD' as val
    from dual
  union all
  select 2 as proc_id, 'DABCD' as val
    from dual
  union all
  select 2 as proc_id, 'ACF' as val
    from dual
  union all
  select 2 as proc_id, 'XXAF' as val from dual)

,
-- Build regexp expression: 1, 'ABC|ACD|XXA'
CDIVN_PATTERN as
 (select dial_id,
         listagg(val, '|') within group(order by dial_id) as val_pattern
    from CDIVN
   group by dial_id)

-- Use this expression by regexp_like
select *
  from CRES c
 where regexp_like(c.val,
                   (select '^' || p.val_pattern
                      from cdivn_pattern p
                     where p.dial_id = 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I would go with:

```
SELECT dia
FROM   CRES
WHERE  pro_id = 2
AND    exists (
         SELECT null
         FROM   CDIVN
         WHERE  dial_id = 1 and
                TO_CHAR(8103434563) like dial_pattern||'%');
```

Comment: No. 
i want something like this...logically...i know this query is wrong but logically i need this
select DIALLED_PATTERN from CRES where PROFILE_ID=1 and 81032144 like (
select DIAL_PATTERN||'%' from CDIVN where dial_pattern_id = 1 );